# how to get words inside a string

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, visual-studio

well i am working with xml but it is not important now, the problem is the next
it returns me something so

```
<xml>blalbalblal asfjñs
fasdf
iduser=dmengelblack; name=angel; lastname=uc;
blablal
iduser=cccarlos; name=carlos; lastname=uc;
```

how do i get (dmengelblack, angel, uc, carlos, uc)

i want to save every  row...

remember all it is inside a string how do i get "dmengelblack", "angel", "uc" save it, everyone in a variable, and save all this in a variable too.. for example

```
string id="dmengelblack";
string name="angel";
string lastname="uc";

all="dmengelblack angel uc"
```

and i need to save the other row too, and all rows it can have

what do i know?

- i know before than username it is "id="
- i know before name it is "name="
- i know before lastname it is "lastname="
- i kwnow everyone finish with ";"

Comment: Why have you tagged four languages? The answer in C# is going to be very different from the answer in C.

Comment: because languajes it is not mind, if not the logic

Comment: If that is supposed to be XML, the person who designed the schema should have his programming license revoked.  You shouldn't embed structured data in an XML text node.  Use elements and attributes ... that's what they are designed for.

Comment: this is not a really xml, but the really xml is a large code, and nobody design it, it is a query using web service, than it return the xm with files... ok?

Comment: @angel - in that case, you should be extracting information from the XML properly using an XML parser.

Comment: i am suing ksoap because i am programming for cell phones with j2me and ksoap2 returns string... for example for a login a did it returns true or false but it doesn't catch it as a bool if not as a string "true" or "false" and i compare if results.equals("true"){ok }else{bad}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way in java is to read the file as a stream, iterate through that and get the substring between

iduser= and ;

and

name= and ;

and

lastname= and ;

EDIT: With this code you will get the list of all the filed you want as

OUTPUT:

```
[iduser=dmengelblack, iduser=cccarlos]
[name=angel, name=carlos]
[lastname=uc, lastname=uc]
```

So now you interate through these list, split the each entry on =, you will the value you wanted at the second index on split.

CODE:

```
String str = "<xml>blalbalblal asfjñs" + "fasdf" 
                    +   "iduser=dmengelblack; name=angel; lastname=uc;"
                    +   "blablal"
                    +   "iduser=cccarlos; name=carlos; lastname=uc;";
        List<String> iduser = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> lastname = new ArrayList<String>();
        int i = 1;
        while(str.indexOf("iduser=", i) > 0) {
            i=str.indexOf("iduser=",i);
            iduser.add(str.substring(i, str.indexOf(";", i)));
            name.add(str.substring(str.indexOf("name=", i), str.indexOf(";", str.indexOf("name=", i))));
            lastname.add(str.substring(str.indexOf("lastname=", i), str.indexOf(";", str.indexOf("lastname=", i))));
            i=str.indexOf("lastname=",i);
        }
        System.out.println(iduser);
        System.out.println(name);
        System.out.println(lastname);
```

hope this helps.

Comment: how to do it? do you have any example

Answer (score 0):

I would use RegEx to extract the pattern of key values into a hast table (dictionary), then use a know key mapping to assign it to the variables you have (iteration with a switch statement or something)

Answer (score 0):

In c# (and other languages, but they will have different syntax) you can split a string into an array of strings like this:

```
string myString = "item1;item2;item3";
string[] separateStrings = myString.Split(';');
```

This will give you a string array like:

```
string[0] = "item1";    
string[1] = "item2";    
string[2] = "item3";
```

I would also suggest you clean up you tags to only tag what you really care about.

Comment: mmm maybe but mystring.split(";"); is not the correct answer because xml has plus ";" in other(";") files than i dont need...